# htaccess rewriterule not working when value contains hyphen

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following rewriterule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)\.html$ $1.php?filter=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

So `example.com/folder/index.php` becomes `example.com/folder/index.html`
and
`example.com/folder/index.php?filter=value` becomes `example.com/folder/index-value.html`

It works, `echo $_GET["filter"]` outputs **value**

But when I try `example.com/folder/index-value-two.html` to output **value-two** I get error:

> Not Found

The requested document was not found on this server.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` is splitting on the second hyphen, not the first one, and so the request it is trying to make is `example.com/folder/index-value.php?filter=two`, which, since `index-value.php` does not exist, gives you a 404 error. Try using this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)-(.*)\.html$ $1.php?filter=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

By changing `.` to `[^\-]` you match any character except a hyphen with the first group, instead of any character. This should split the URL at the first `-`.